# New-localuser with joined string password

Tags: powershell, securestring

What is going wrong with this:

```
$pass= "kissa"+"koira"
$pw= ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force

#Create local user
New-LocalUser -Name $username -Password $pw -UserMayNotChangePassword -AccountNeverExpires -PasswordNeverExpires
```

It creates a user, does not nag about anything.
But when I try to login the password is not accepted.

Password should be kissakoira. This is of over simplified example, im trying to create a password with three variables, but even this simple joined string does not work. Its not password complexity as plain kissa or koira work, but not the joined string.

Comment: What do you expect the password to be? `Write-Host $Pass` or something like: `'kissa"+"koira'`? Do other passwords work?

Comment: You might have password complexity requirements enabled. In such cases it is possible to set a weak password, but one cannot log in with it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Password should be kissakoira. This is of over simplified example, im trying to create a password with three variables, but even this simple joined string does not work. Its not password complexity as plain kissa or koira work, but not the joined string.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

$pw="kissa"+"koira"| ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

#Create local user
New-LocalUser -Name $username -Password $pw -UserMayNotChangePassword -AccountNeverExpires -PasswordNeverExpires

Comment: what is the meaningful difference between your Answer code and the Question code? what is different & why?

Comment: That is what I am wondering myself. Only difference is that the answer works and original does not. Does the ConvertTo-SecureString not like variables or something..

Comment: generally, an Answer otta more about `why` than just a blob of code with no rationale. ///// also, you likely otta add code formatting around the code to make it easy to read. [*grin*]